How to add the IEEE format requirement (in Chinese) field in my referee
I cited a Chinese paper, and according to IEEE requirements, I need to add an "in Chinese" field after the title.

Welcome to the site! Could you please give a MWE that shows what citation format you’re using and where you want the “in Chinese” field? A description of the IEEE requirement would be good as well.

It would also help to know whether you are required to use PDFLaTeX, or can use another engine.

Is something stopping you from changing the title field to, say, title={你好世界 (in Chinese)}?

@Mico I think they mean the title of the paper they cited?

@Mico This is the form I use, but the format requires me to put the (in chinese) field outside the title and in front of the journal name.

@wcgwcg - Please provide more information, then, about what the full/augmented title is supposed to look like.

You can use the titleaddon field, in any case.
If you need to customise the punctuation too, you shall manage the title macro. If you are using the IEEE style, you have to manage the title-in-maintitle macro too.
I recommend to create a new bibmacro, precise to manage the titleaddon field and its punctuation.
\newbibmacro{titleaddon}{%
    \iffieldundef{titleaddon}%
        {}%
        {\setunit{\addspace}}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
        \printfield{titleaddon}}}

Keep in mind that:

I assumed that you don't want any punctuation between the titles (the title and subtitle fields) and the titleaddon field, except the single space, but, of course, you can modify the \setunit argument;
just for example, I wrote the titleaddon field within parens, but you can take off it, of course.

Now, you have to input this macro within the title macro and, if you are using the IEEE style, the title-in-maintitle one.
So, here you are the modification.
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{title}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}}%
        {}%
        {\printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[sentencecase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[sentencecase]{subtitle}}%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{titleaddon}}

\renewbibmacro*{title-in-maintitle}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{title}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}}%
        {}%
        {\printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{titleaddon}}

Now, with these two new macros, you can manage the titleaddon field just modifying the new titleaddon macro.
Here you are a MWEB.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro{titleaddon}{%
    \iffieldundef{titleaddon}%
        {}%
        {\setunit{\addspace}}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
        \printfield{titleaddon}}}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{title}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}}%
        {}%
        {\printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[sentencecase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[sentencecase]{subtitle}}%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{titleaddon}}

\renewbibmacro*{title-in-maintitle}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{title}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}}%
        {}%
        {\printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{titleaddon}}

\begin{filecontents*}{myref.bib}
    @article{diliberto2028,
        author={Diliberto, Oliviero},gender={sm},
        title={The Chinese Civil Code},
        titleaddon={in Chinese},
        journaltitle={A New Chinese Legal Journal},
        volume={1},number={1},year={2028},eid={1},
        doi={10.1000/182}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{myref.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{diliberto2028}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

You will get something like that.

